# Javascript stuck when calling an API method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I use AJAX to gather data from a MySQL database through PHP, but all the Javascript functions on the web page get stuck when I'm trying to call an API method using the gathered data.

AJAX code structure:

```
$.post(
  "userdata.php",
  { id: ""+userid+"" },
  function(data) {
    // call my API when AJAX call completed
  }
);
```

The above code works perfectly. For example I tried `alert(data);`, it alerts the requested user's name.

My full code:

```
$.post(
  "userdata.php",
  { id: ""+userid+"" },
  function(data) {
    $.formdata.clear();
    $.formdata.addname(data);
  }
);
```

My API also works fine. I think the error is because of the `$` sign, like `$.post` and inside of it again `$.formdata`.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` symbol is a name to reference `jQuery`. Here you are trying to reference a property of jQuery called `formdata`.

The `formdata` object looks like something you're written, since it has `clear` and `addname` methods. Try calling it without the dollar sign.

```
formdata.clear();
formdata.addname(data);
```

Comment: btw I found that my API is not fully loaded when making requests to API through JS function, As a result browser stops all the javascript functionality... Thank you for your answer...